# Use javascript to view multiple urls in iframe

Tags: javascript, arrays, url, iframe

I want to view multiple `Urls` in an `iframe` using `JavaScript Arrays`. I want to know how can I do that. I don't just need a description but also some sample code.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please first read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking questions. Stackoverflow isn't here to do your work for you. Show us what you tried, some code, etc.

Comment: One `iframe` can only display one url at the same time. If you want to display multiple urls at the same time you need multiple iframes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go with the solution https://codepen.io/Shiladitya/pen/qjvOjV

```js
var array = ["https://www.google.com",       "https://codepen.io/","https://www.amazon.in", "http://www.stackoverflow.com"];

var cnt = 0;
$('button').click(function(){
 $('iframe').attr('src', array[cnt]);
  cnt++;
  if(cnt == array.length){
   cnt = 0;
  }
});
```

```css
iframe {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 

<button type="submit">Next Iframe
</button>

<iframe>

</iframe>
```

I assume you want to show only one URL at a time in iframe.

Comment: Welcome @FahadMaqsoodQazi :)